# ios add padding inside uiimageview so some of background shows

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView and I want to add UIImage to it. All of this I am doing in interface builder (i.e. xib file). Is there a way to add bottom padding to the UIImageView so that some of the background shows below the UIImage?

Comment: You can either add it to a container view or set the border with of the UIImageView to your desired padding. [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:10.0];

Answer (score -1):

A work around would be to put one view inside another.  You can size the top view as you wish to only expose the back UIImageView where you like it.  Insert your photo in the top view.

[image]

Comment: Well, Apple drops the ball on this one and android wins. In android all I have to do is set the padding right there in the "Interface builder". Using two views to accomplish this simple task is an apparent overkill.